# Explain how this loop works to me please - Python tkinter

Tags: python, loops, tkinter

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

v = IntVar()
v.set(1)  # initializing the choice, i.e. Python

languages = [
    ("Python",1),
    ("Perl",2),
    ("Java",3),
    ("C++",4),
    ("C",5)
]

def ShowChoice():
    print v.get()

Label(root, 
      text="""Choose your favourite 
programming language:""",
      justify = LEFT,
      padx = 20).pack()

for txt, val in languages:
    Radiobutton(root, 
                text=txt,
                padx = 20, 
                variable=v, 
                command=ShowChoice,
                value=val).pack(anchor=W)

mainloop()
```

Could someone please explain how this loop works to create radiobuttons? As I'm finding it very difficult to follow

Comment: Perhaps you are referring to the apparent lack of bindings for each object? A reference is implicitly added to the root element when the object is created.

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 1):

When you do this:

```
languages = [
    ("Python",1),
    ("Perl",2),
    ("Java",3),
    ("C++",4),
    ("C",5)
]
for txt, val in languages:
    Radiobutton(..., text=txt, value=val, ...)
```

Is exactly the same as this:

```
Radiobutton(root, text="Python", value=1, ...)
Radiobutton(root, text="Perl", value=2, ...)
Radiobutton(root, text="Java", value=3, ...)
Radiobutton(root, text="C++", value=4, ...)
Radiobutton(root, text="C", value=5, ...)
```